# JavaScript code to enable - disable people editor control not working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: 2013, javascript, browser-compatibility

I have an application page in which two radio buttons and a people editor control is there.

My requirement is, if radio button "Yes" is checked then the people editor control should be enabled other wise it should be disabled.

My JavaScript code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var radYes = document.getElementById("<%= rbtnReferralYes.ClientID %>");
        var radNo = document.getElementById("<%= rbtnReferralNo.ClientID %>");
        var peopleEditor = document.getElementById("<%= peReferralUsers.ClientID %>");
        $(peopleEditor).prop('disabled',true);
        $(radYes).click(function() {                    
            $(peopleEditor).prop('disabled',false);
        });
        $(radNo).click(function() {                 
            $(peopleEditor).prop('disabled',true);
        });
    });
</script>
```

My problem is that this code is working fine in IE but not working in Chrome and Firefox.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can it with `.attr()` like this:

```
$(peopleEditor).attr("disabled", 'disabled');
```

Or you can try to hide and show with `.hide()` and `.show()` but then its completely not visible.

EDIT:
You have to check if your radiobutton is checked:

```
    $(peopleEditor).prop('disabled',true);
    $(radYes).click(function() {                    
       if($(radYes).is(':checked')) { 
          $(peopleEditor).prop('disabled',false);
       } 
    });
    $(radNo).click(function() {
       if($(radNo).is(':checked')) { {                 
          $(peopleEditor).prop('disabled',true);
       }
    });
```

[Radiobuttons with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142300/javascript-jquery-radio-button-click)

Or you can use only one Checkbox for enabeling/disabling the peopleEditor field

Comment: thanks for answering sir, I tried this way but not working. :-(

Comment: any errors for ff and chrome?

Comment: No sir, I am not getting any error. I debugged the JavaScript in Firebug(in firefox). and found that the break point does not get executed placed over `$(radYes).click(function() {$(peopleEditor).prop('disabled',false);});`

Comment: you may have to check if the button is checked, see my edited answer

Comment: I tried the edited code also, but not working sir.

Comment: is jQuery already loaded when running this code(especially in ff and chrome)?

Comment: Yes sir, it is loaded.

Comment: can you try it with a checkbox?